# Use channel to limit the number of active go routines

Tags: go

I'm reading the "The Go Programming Language"
One way to limit the number of running go routines is to use a "counting semaphore".

The other way is [Limiting number of go routines running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55203251/limiting-number-of-go-routines-running)

I am allowing 2 more go routines in the case. I'm getting deadlock error.
What causes the deadlock in my code?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    //"context"
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    max := 2
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    squares := make(chan int)
    tokens := make(chan struct{}, max)
    for i := 20; i >= 1; i-- {
        tokens <- struct{}{}
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(n int) {
            defer func() { <-tokens }()
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Println("run go routine ", getGID())
            squares <- Square(n)

        }(i)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(squares)
    }()

    for s := range squares {
        fmt.Println("Get square: ", s)

    }
}

func Square(num int) int {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(num))
    fmt.Println(num * num)
    return num * num
}

func getGID() uint64 {
    b := make([]byte, 64)
    b = b[:runtime.Stack(b, false)]
    b = bytes.TrimPrefix(b, []byte("goroutine "))
    b = b[:bytes.IndexByte(b, ' ')]
    n, _ := strconv.ParseUint(string(b), 10, 64)
    return n
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goroutines block on sending to `squares`.  Main is not receiving on `squares` because it blocks on starting the the goroutines.

Fix by moving the code that starts the goroutines to a goroutine.  This allows main to continue executing to the receive on `squares`.

```
squares := make(chan int)
go func() {
    max := 2
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    tokens := make(chan struct{}, max)
    for i := 20; i >= 1; i-- {
        tokens <- struct{}{}
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(n int) {
            defer func() { <-tokens }()
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Println("run go routine ", getGID())
            squares <- Square(n)

        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(squares)
}()

fmt.Println("About to receive")
for s := range squares {
    fmt.Println("Get square: ", s)

}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VFINCenQkp4).