# Trying to use channels in go but data is not properly sent/received into the channel

Tags: http, go, channel

The hope is to quickly parse a very large number of similar URLs (only one 'id' element differs from one to the next) and dump the response body into a channel that will later be queried by the main function and used to build a text file.

Inside the `getpageCanal()` function, the body seems to be ok, but after that, I don't understand why the channel doesn't properly load the body string.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    initial := "https://www1.medion.de/downloads/index.pl?op=detail&id="
    ending := "&type=treiber&lang=uk"

    links := []string{}
    os.Remove("dump.txt")
    dumpFile, _ := os.Create("dump.txt")
    c := make(chan string)
    for i := 16000; i < 16004; i++ {
        links = append(links, initial+fmt.Sprint(i)+ending)
    }
    fmt.Println(links[0])
    for _, link := range links {
        //the hope is to make this a go routine, but first I need to just make it work
        getpageCanal(c, link)
    }

    for el := range c {
        fmt.Println(el)
        n, err := dumpFile.WriteString(el)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        if n == 0 {
            fmt.Println(" nothing written in main")
        }
    }
}

func getpageCanal(canal chan string, url string) {
    defer close(canal)
    page, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("you done fucked up, boy")
    }
    content, er2 := ioutil.ReadAll(page.Body)
    //fmt.Println(content)
    if er2 != nil {
        fmt.Println(er2)
    }
    canal <- string(content)
}
```

Comment: This will not work without running getpageCanal in a separate goroutine. The write to the channel will block because there isn't a goroutine listening to it. Also, it should not close the channel.

Comment: Thank you @BurakSerdar! I modified the code and now it works as intended (made the call to getpageCanal() a go routine and deleted the close(channel) line

Comment: `getpageCanal`  error handling is wrong for 2 reasons: first, you don't output any information about the error.  Second, you attempt to process the page body anyway.

Answer (score 1):

After modifying the code as instructed by the first comments (not closing the channel after each call and making the call to the worker function a go routine) I will now provide you with a working version:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    initial := "https://www1.medion.de/downloads/index.pl?op=detail&id="
    ending := "&type=treiber&lang=uk"

    links := []string{}
    os.Remove("dump.txt")
    dumpFile, _ := os.Create("dump.txt")
    c := make(chan string)
    for i := 16000; i < 16004; i++ {
        links = append(links, initial+fmt.Sprint(i)+ending)
    }
    fmt.Println(links[0])
    for _, link := range links {
        go getpageCanal(c, link)
    }

    for el := range c {
        fmt.Println(el)
        n, err := dumpFile.WriteString(el)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        if n == 0 {
            fmt.Println(" nothing written in main")
        }
    }
}

func getpageCanal(canal chan string, url string) {
    //defer close(canal)
    page, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("you done fucked up, boy")
    }
    content, er2 := ioutil.ReadAll(page.Body)
    //fmt.Println(content)
    if er2 != nil {
        fmt.Println(er2)
    }
    canal <- string(content)
}
```

Comment: (1) getpageCanal should not blunder when http.Get returns an error (2) close the response body when http.Get is successful: `defer page.Body.Close()` (3) this program can easily breach limits on open file descriptors.  Consider using a fixed size worker pool. Here's [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55203322/5728991) of many on SO.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, I appreciate the worker pool approach that you've been so kind to point out. I'll definitely try and implement it